# SQL Server 2008 R2 DB stuck on restoring

Tags: sql-server

I've disabled the witness server and now side 1 is stuck in restoring state and I am unable to get it out of that state. I've tried to restore the DB and now I'm getting the following error. Any suggestions? I've made a backup of the side 2 db and before I just do a restore with that I wanted to see if any of you have come across a more graceful fix.

Thanks!

```
RESTORE DATABASE DBNAME WITH RECOVERY;
```

Error message:

> Msg 4303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The roll forward start point is now at log sequence number (LSN) ###700006. Additional roll forward past LSN ###900001 is required to complete the restore sequence.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Instead of a restore you could attach the MDF file to the side 1 instance? You can do this without the log file and SQL server will spin up a new one.

Comment: Did you take a tail log backup? It looks like you have/had an incomplete (maybe corrupted)transaction log

Comment: Did you apply latest patch? This link might helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191459(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ended dropping the database and restoring the backup:

```
DROP DATABASE DBNAME;
```

Then Restored database with SQL Studio.

Comment: If you're somewhere out there - you can mark your answer as the accepted to close this question!